# парсинг пакета tcp/ip

Tags: java, сокет, tcp-ip

есть клиент который принимает поток byte[] необходимо.из него формировать отдельные массивы по параметрам.это все должно идти в режиме получения пакет
Формат  массивов param1=1 байт param2=2-ой байт param3=3-ой байт param4=6-ой байт param5=7-ой байт

```
    import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;

    public class Client {
        public static void main(String[] ar) {
            int serverPort = 5050; // здесь обязательно нужно указать порт к которому привязывается сервер.
            String address = "127.0.0.1"; // это IP-адрес компьютера, где исполняется наша серверная программа.

            // Здесь указан адрес того самого компьютера где будет исполняться и клиент.

            try {
                Socket socket = new Socket(address, serverPort);
               byte[]s=read(socket);
               for(int i=0;i<s.length;i++){
                   System.out.println(s[i]);
               }


               /* OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream();
//String str="hello";
DataOutputStream out1=new DataOutputStream(os);

                InputStream in = socket.getInputStream();
                ArrayList <Integer> list=new ArrayList<>();
                int value;
                int r;


                while( (r = in.read()) >= 0 ) {
                    System.out.printf("%02X ", r);
                    System.out.println(r);
                    list.add(r);
                }

*/
                }
             catch (Exception x) {
                x.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

       static public byte[] read(Socket socket) throws IOException
        {
            byte[] array = new byte[280 * 1024];
            int arrayPointer = 0;
            DataInputStream din = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
            int readCount;
            while ((readCount = din.read(buffer)) != -1)
            {
                System.arraycopy(buffer, 0, array, arrayPointer, readCount);
                arrayPointer += readCount;
            }
            return array;
        }



    }
```

Comment: Откройте спецификацию TCP/IP - там всё описано. Приведите пример того что у вас не получается.

Comment: я уже получил пакет но мне нужное его разбивать на массивы